# get filename from access attachment

Tags: vba, ms-access, filenames, attachment, ms-access-2013

I've got a bit of VBA running in access. Its purpose is to output a pipe delineated string in order to provide exports/back ups of existing tables. It's working well but there's another feature I'd like to add. One of the tables it may be run against contains attachments and I would like the attachment filename to appear under the 'attachment' field. Currently the code just sticks a warning in there but I'd like something more relevant.

The code currently reads each field name in the designated table, splitting them with a pipe (|). It then goes to a new line and repeats the process with the values in each field. Relevant bit of code below:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Table, dbOpenSnapshot)
rs.Filter = srchString
Set rsFilt = rs.OpenRecordset()
fieldCount = rsFilt.Fields.Count
recordTot = rsFilt.RecordCount

If recordTot <> 0 Then

    rsFilt.MoveFirst

    Dim o As Integer

    For o = 0 To fieldCount - 1
        fieldNames = fieldNames & rsFilt.Fields(o).Name & "|"
    Next o


    Do While rsFilt.EOF = False
        For o = 0 To fieldCount - 1
            If rsFilt.Fields(o).Type <> 101 Then
                oldDataSet = oldDataSet & Nz(rsFilt.Fields(o).Value, "") & "|"
            Else
                oldDataSet = oldDataSet & "attached files not saved in logs" & "|"
            End If
        Next o
        oldDataSet = oldDataSet & vbNewLine
        rsFilt.MoveNext

    Loop
Else

    fieldNames = "No " & Table & " for this member."

End If

createRecordSnapshot = fieldNames & vbNewLine & oldDataSet

End Function
```

Each record has only one attachment associated with it. I'd like some way to fetch that filename as a string.

Many thanks,

Comment: Which version of Access is this database? What is the field type of these "attachments"? Looking at the Table Design view for that field, in what property is the file name stored?

Comment: Access 2013, Field type is Attachment, I can't see anything helpful in the field properties of design view. Just Caption and required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, the only way to access this information is through an `Attachment` control on a Form. You could make a simple form with just this control on it, load it as part of your code and access it in the loop.

Here's an example of looping through the records in a form and reading the `filename` property of the `Attachment` control:

```
Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Attachment
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set frm = Application.Forms("Form1")
Set ctl = frm.Controls("test") 'An Attachment control
frm.RecordsetClone.MoveLast
i = frm.Recordset.RecordCount
For j = 0 To i - 1
    Debug.Print ctl.FileName
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, frm.Name, acNext
Next
```

Comment: This looks like the best bet, but given the extra complexity it probably isn't worth implementing. But still, thanks for your time and the answer!